# Validate url using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

Someone please help.

I am trying to write some regular expression to eliminate files while crawling web pages.
I have URLs like

**Allowed URLS:**
http://example.com/about/ 
http://example.com/test.html 
http://example.com/about/careers.html

I need to eliminate if there is any page which is not html/xml pages like below URL.

**URLs not allowed/required:**
http://example.com/download/file_download.tar.gz 
http://example.com/download/file.iso 
http://example.com/download/something.dll

How to write regular expression to eliminate invalid URLs?
I am using javascript to achieve this.

i tried something like this.

```
URL = 'http://example.com';
filename = URL.substring(URL.lastIndexOf("/")+1, URL.length);
if(filename.match(/^#/g) || filename.match(/#$/g) || filename.match(/[^html]/g) || filename.match(/[^ ]/g)){    // filename contains id,
```

Comment: Those "In-Valid URL" examples you gave are NOT invalid URLs. If you want to exclude them, you need to completely and thoroughly explain *exactly* what YOUR definition of invalid is; do not just give us a few examples, because your definition of invalid and what is really invalid as a url format are 2 different things.  Also, just gonna mention as a sidenote.. I'm kind of curious how you expect to crawl a website with javascript.  Are you using node.js?

Comment: yeah. its not invalid urls. but i wanted to ignore those URLs while crawling websites. So i need to exclude them.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below regular expression to filter your url

```
(((http://)|(http://www.)|(www.))(example.com)([\/A-z]*)((.html)|(.xml))*)
```

Answer (score 0):

just try it this way `/^(.*(?:\/|html|htm|php|xml))\s*$/`

```
if (filename.match(/^(.*(?:\/|html|htm|php|xml))\s*$/)) {
    // yupp, it's ok
}
```